# How to convert base64 to hex string without using builtin function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64, data-conversion, thingsboard

I want to convert a base64 value i.e: `AQ0gIAcDExUQAQECAWQW` to a hexadecimal string `010D20200703131510010102016416` using JavaScript in thingsboard. While using atob function i am getting this error
`javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "atob" is not defined in at line number 24`

Comment: The question is "Why"?

Comment: Because i cant use atob function

Answer (score 0):

You can look at someone elses implementation of atob and copy their process.
E.g.
https://github.com/jsdom/abab/blob/master/lib/atob.js

Answer (score -1):

Why not using `atob` ?

```js
function base64ToHexFunc(str) {
  const encodedData = atob(str);
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < encodedData.length; i++) {
    const hex = encodedData.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    result += (hex.length === 2 ? hex : '0' + hex);
  }
  return result.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(base64ToHexFunc("AQ0gIAcDExUQAQECAWQW"));
```

Comment: Array.from(atob('AQ0gIAcDExUQAQECAWQW')).map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')).join('').toUpperCase()

// "010D20200703131510010102016416"

Comment: I can't use atob because while using that it shows function is undefined.I need to use it for thingsboard platform

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "atob" is not defined in at line number 20